# How to check part id in Juniper Router?

Tags: juniper

In Cisco router I am able to see part id's

```
XXXXXX#show inventory 

NAME: "subslot 0/0 transceiver 5", DESCR: "GE LX"
PID: FTLF1318P3BTL-RN  , VID: A   , SN: PV90L6P
```

But when I execute show chassis hardware I am able to see only serial number but the part number will just show **NON-JNPR**

```
XXX@YYYYYYYT> show chassis hardware 
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                XXXXXXXXXXXX      ACX2200
Midplane         REV 10   XXX-XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX      ACX2200
Routing Engine            BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Routing Engine
FEB 0                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Forwarding Engine Processor
FPC 0                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 1GE(LAN) RJ45
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 1GE(LAN) RJ45
  MIC 1                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 1GE(LAN) SFP, RJ45
    PIC 1                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 1GE(LAN) SFP, RJ45
      Xcvr 1              NON-JNPR     EC143700380278    SFP-LX10
      Xcvr 2              NON-JNPR     NSD00A6           SFP-SX
      Xcvr 3              NON-JNPR     NSD0G0L           SFP-SX
```

I have tried `#show chassis hardware extensive` but no luck

Some information is censored.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
show Interface transceiver
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using 3rd party transceivers that are not coded to be compatible with Juniper. When working with Juniper switches they will accept a wide range of transceivers from other brands, which is why these will still work, but they are not properly coded.  If these were properly coded you would see a Juniper part# instead of NON-JNPR, such as 740-011616, the Rev will also be filled out.